# Returning HelpText class instead of string works unexpectedly

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I'm using `CommandLine Parser` API to handle my application's command line arguments.

In the [sample page](http://commandline.codeplex.com/), there's a piece of code :

```
 [HelpOption]
  public string GetUsage() {
    return HelpText.AutoBuild(this, (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
  }
```

**It does compile**.

But, actually the return value of `HelpText.AutoBuild()` is HelpText instance , which inherits immediatly object. 
Moreover, AFAIK, string is a sealed class, which cannot be inherited.

How could this be ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of magic is made by an `implicit operator string` ([See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)).
 **`HelpText` class has definitely one.**

---

A sample usage :

```
public class A 
{
      ......
   public override String ToString() 
   {
        return "AAA" ; 
   }

   public static implicit operator string (A a) 
   {
        return a.ToString() ; 
   }
}
```

It allows you to do something like this :

```
string aString = new A() ;  // new A().ToString() is called by the implicit operator
```

and of course, you can do :

```
public string MethodMan() 
{
     return new A(); 
}
```